# Could not resolve project :@react-native-community_viewpager

Tags: react-native

I have uninstalled `@react-native-community_viewpager` since it is migrated to some other package. since then I am getting mentioned error. I tried

1.deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling

2.`npm start --reset cache`

3.`react-native start --reset-cache`

4.Deleted whole project from my Mac Pro with M1 chip and then created everything newly

But still I am getting this error. Can some one help me to get rid of this error. Thank You

Comment: did you cmd+shift+f in your IDE and make sure no references to the package are left?

Comment: also, make sure it's fully removed from your gradle files

Comment: @kai I have deleted all the references.now everything is ok. Thank you 